# How well does Sitecore 7 lend itself to presenting external JSON data?

Tags: json, sitecore, sitecore7

I'm asking because I am not sure what kind of person we'll need to hire (ASP? Sitecore? Angular? JQuery) to implement the following for us:

Our school is looking to make data on courses (JSON format, about 600 courses) available as an “online catalog.” The static info (programs information, resources, etc.) will be hosted in Sitecore 7.

We’d like to see the online course catalog closely integrated with the rest of the site, so we’re looking for best approaches on how to do that.

Some manipulation of the JSON data is required: course detail pages should be simple enough, but we’ll also need to have course listings (not necessarily displaying all 600 courses at once, in one long list, but segmented by programs, class formats & locations, etc) as well as a “course search” functionality.

Would Sitecore do that well enough out-of-the-box, or would it be better/easier to go with something like Angular JS on top of Sitecore?

Please ask me for additional info if I had left something important out or if anything is unclear.

Comment: Your question may be considered of topic for here.  See http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic   It skirts close to being both opinion based and also "5. Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming."

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Would it help if I re-phrased the question as follows?
"Displaying external JSON data (read-only): would you use Sitecore's Web API, or utilize AJAX instead?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Dijkgraaf comment but to provide you with answer; Sitecore is suitable for your requirements but is a framework which means out of the box it won't meet your requirement so you will need a Developer who knows Sitecore and by extension .NET (Sitecore is built on .NET).

These developers will also know how to work with JSON, most likely serving it up from Sitecore via a .NET technology called Web API. The JSON can then be manipulated with Javascript or AngularJS. It is not as common for Sitecore developers to be familiar with AngularJS however.

Comment: Out the box, they could use Sitecore Item Web API, not sure I would use that directly from client code (put a wrapper around it to not expose the queries) but it is mostly possible: http://sitecorestrategy.blogspot.co.uk/2014/03/content-as-service-and-sitecore-item.html

Comment: I agree, I'm not comfortable with using Sitecore Item Web API directly from client code. A wrapper is a good shout, I had a good experience with writing something in Web API akin to EntityService exists now and actually served it up via AngularJS

Comment: I see where you're coming from – I think my inexperience with the frameworks and how they relate to one another made me misjudge the appropriateness of my question on this forum.

Comment: JRobbins: that synopsis is extremely helpful – just what I've been looking for. Many thanks!

Comment: Its understandable as the breadth of the frameworks can cover so much each with a different approach. Glad my response helped - if you it answers your question please mark it as such to help others.

Comment: Since our Sitecore web app will not be expected to create/update/remove JSON items (JSON will be "read only," retrieved from an external source), I found this lead on what **presentation of the JSON data** in SItecore will entail: http://johnnewcombe.net/blog/sitecore-part-6